# Is it possible to convert char[] to char*?

Tags: c, char

I'm doing an assignment where we have to read a series of strings from a file into an array. I have to call a cipher algorithm on the array (cipher transposes 2D arrays). So, at first I put all the information from the file into a 2D array, but I had a lot of trouble with conflicting types in the rest of my code (specifically trying to set `char[]` to `char*`). So, I decided to switch to an array of pointers, which made everything a lot easier in most of my code.

But now I need to convert `char*` to `char[]` and back again, but I can't figure it out. I haven't been able to find anything on google. I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It sounds like you're confused between pointers and arrays. Pointers and arrays (in this case `char *` and `char []`) are [not the same thing.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

- An array `char a[SIZE]` says that the value at the location of `a` is an array of length `SIZE`
- A pointer `char *a;` says that the value at the location of `a` is a pointer to a `char`. This can be combined with pointer arithmetic to behave like an array (eg, `a[10]` is 10 entries past wherever `a` points)

In memory, it looks like this (example taken from [the FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)):

```
 char a[] = "hello";  // array

   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+

 char *p = "world"; // pointer

   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: |  *======> | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It's easy to be confused about the difference between pointers and arrays, because in many cases, an array reference "decays" to a pointer to it's first element. This means that in many cases (such as when passed to a function call) arrays become pointers. If you'd like to know more, [this section of the C FAQ describes the differences in detail](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

One major practical difference is that the compiler knows how long an array is. Using the examples above:

```
char a[] = "hello";  
char *p =  "world";  

sizeof(a); // 6 - one byte for each character in the string,
           // one for the '\0' terminator
sizeof(p); // whatever the size of the pointer is
           // probably 4 or 8 on most machines (depending on whether it's a 
           // 32 or 64 bit machine)
```

Without seeing your code, it's hard to recommend the best course of action, but I suspect changing to use pointers everywhere will solve the problems you're currently having. Take note that now:

- You will need to initialise memory wherever the arrays used to be. Eg, `char a[10];` will become `char *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));`, followed by a check that `a != NULL`. Note that you don't actually need to say `sizeof(char)` in this case, because `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1. I left it in for completeness.
- Anywhere you previously had `sizeof(a)` for array length will need to be replaced by the length of the memory you allocated (if you're using strings, you could use `strlen()`, which counts up to the `'\0'`).
- You will need a make a corresponding call to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) for each call to `malloc()`. This tells the computer you are done using the memory you asked for with `malloc()`. If your pointer is `a`, just write `free(a);` at a point in the code where you know you no longer need whatever `a` points to.

As another answer pointed out, if you want to get the address of the start of an array, you can use:

```
char* p = &a[0]
```

You can read this as "char pointer `p` becomes the address of element `[0]` of `a`".

Comment: In the last example, can't `char *p = &a[0]` be simplified to just `char *p = &a` ?

Comment: @thom_nic: No, because `&a` has the type `char (*)[6]`, ie, a pointer to an array of six characters. This isn't the same as `char *`, so you'll get a warning. However, you can say `char *p = a;`, because an array reference can [decay into a pointer to its first element](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html). I used the longer form here, because it better illustrates what's happening.

Comment: Ah, I see that the words I used on the second last line could have been confusing. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I would also add that in case of `char *a`, if `a` is uninitialized or points to a string literal, like `char *a = "hello"`, then `a[0]` or `a[1]` would be a valid read, but any attempt to write to what `a` points to would not be valid, resulting in segmentation fault.

Answer (score 22):

If you have 
`char[] c`
then you can do
`char* d = &c[0]`
and access element c[1] by doing `*(d+1)`, etc.

Comment: Or you can just `char *d = c;`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declare them as arrays if you want to use use them as pointers. You can simply reference pointers as if they were multi-dimensional arrays. Just create it as a pointer to a pointer and use `malloc`:

```
int i;
int M=30, N=25;
int ** buf;
buf = (int**) malloc(M * sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    buf[i] = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

and then you can reference `buf[3][5]` or whatever.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: It's necessary because `malloc()` returns a `void *`, which needs to be cast to an `int *` to be stored in `buf`.

Comment: No, the cast is not necessary.  In C, an expression of type `void*` can be implicitly converted to any pointer-to-object (or pointer-to-incomplete) type.  See question 7.7b of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) and section 6.5.16.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  (C++ has different rules, which would be relevant if we were discussing C++.)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me except strtok

```
#include <string.h>
```

Then use `strtok`

```
char some[] = "some string";
char *p = strtok(some, "");
```

`strtok` is used to split strings. But you can see that I split it on nothing `""`

Now you have a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to convert from char [] to char* is with strdup() function. Use it as follows:

```
Char word[] = “Hello”;
Char *p = strdup(word);
```

Note:

You need to #include <string.h> and <stdlib.h>. Also, you will need to use the free(p) method after you are done with the pointer. The strdup() function allocates a block of memory on the heap I believe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would do this. If you have an array, e.g. `char word[] = "Hello";`, then `char *p = word;` gives you a pointer to the first element of the array due to array decay. BTW, the C type is `char`, not `Char`.