# Pointers and Arrays -- Learn C the hard way

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This question is from Learn C the Hard Way by Zed Shaw. It's about pointers and arrays. We are given some code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // create two arrays we care about
  int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
  char *names[] = {
      "Alan", "Frank",
      "Mary", "John", "Lisa"
  };

  // safely get the size of ages
  int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
  int i = 0;

  // first way using indexing
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      printf("%s has %d years alive.\n",
              names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  printf("---\n");

  // setup the pointers to the start of the arrays
  int *cur_age = ages;
  char **cur_name = names;

  // second way using pointers
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      printf("%s is %d years old.\n",
            *(cur_name+i), *(cur_age+i));
  }

  printf("---\n");

  // third way, pointers are just arrays
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      printf("%s is %d years old again.\n",
              cur_name[i], cur_age[i]);
  }

  printf("---\n");

  // fourth way with pointers in a stupid complex way
  for(cur_name = names, cur_age = ages;
          (cur_age - ages) < count;
          cur_name++, cur_age++)
  {
      printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n",
              *cur_name, *cur_age);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The directive is to "[rewrite all the array usage in this program so that it's pointers.](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex15.html#extra-credit)" Does this mean to do something like?

```
int *ptr;
ptr = &ages[0]
```

Comment: It could also mean allocating arrays dynamically using `malloc`. Regarding your `ptr` assignment `ptr = ages;` should be enough.

Comment: pointer and arrays are interchangeable in many situations.  For example, at the top, *argv[] could be replaced with **argv.  You could probably finish the assignment by simply removing all the square brackets and placing an * on the front of every array.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact exercise in question?

Comment: BTW - Where the code has a comment 'safe get the size of ages', it's wrong; if someone changed the type of ages, it would give the wrong value. A safer way to get the size of ages would be `sizeof(ages) / sizeof(*ages)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let me start off by saying something a little off topic:

- I don't think this is a very good book. I think it confuses some topics to make them seem harder than they really are. For a better advanced C book, I would recommend [Deep C Secrets by Peter van der Linden](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298), and for a beginner's book, I'd recommend the original [K & R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)

Anyway, it looks like you're looking at the extra credit exercises from [this chapter](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex15.html).

- Another aside- I don't think this is an especially sensible exercise for learning (another answer pointed out the question isn't formed to make sense), so this discussion is going to get a little complex. I would instead recommend the exercises from Chapter 5 of [K & R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

First we need to understand that [pointers are not the same as arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). I've expanded on this in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628309/790070), and I'm going to borrow the same diagram from the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). Here's what's happening in memory when  we declare an array or a pointer:

```
 char a[] = "hello";  // array

   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+

 char *p = "world"; // pointer

   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: |  *======> | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So, in the code from the book, when we say:

```
int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
```

We get:

```
      +----+----+----+----+---+
ages: | 23 | 43 | 12 | 89 | 2 |
      +----+----+----+----+---+
```

I'm going to use an illegal statement for the purpose of explanation - if we **could** have said:

```
int *ages = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2}; // The C grammar prohibits initialised array
                                 // declarations being assigned to pointers, 
                                 // but I'll get to that
```

It would have resulted in:

```
      +---+     +----+----+----+----+---+
ages: | *=====> | 23 | 43 | 12 | 89 | 2 |
      +---+     +----+----+----+----+---+
```

Both of these can be accessed the same way later on - the first element "23" can be accessed by `ages[0]`, regardless of whether it's an array or a pointer. So far so good.

However, when we want to get the count we run in to problems. C doesn't know how big arrays are - it only knows how big (in bytes) the variables it knows about are. This means, with the array, you can work out the size by saying:

```
int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
```

or, more safely:

```
int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(ages[0]);
```

In the array case, this says:

```
int count = the number of bytes in (an array of 6 integers) / 
                 the number of bytes in (an integer)
```

which correctly gives the length of the array. However, for the pointer case, it will read:

```
int count = the number of bytes in (**a pointer**) /
                 the number of bytes in (an integer)
```

which is almost certainly not the same as the length of the array. Where pointers to arrays are used, we need to use another method to work out how long the array is. In C, it is normal to either:

- Remember how many elements there were:

  ```
  int *ages = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2}; // Remember you can't actually
                                   // assign like this, see below
  int ages_length = 5;
  for (i = 0 ; i < ages_length; i++) {
  ```
- or, keep a sentinel value (that will never occur as an actual value in the array) to indicate the end of the array:

  ```
  int *ages = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2, -1}; // Remember you can't actually
                                       // assign like this, see below
  for (i = 0; ages[i] != -1; i++) {
  ```

  (this is how strings work, using the special NUL value '\0' to indicate the end of a string)

---

Now, remember that I said you can't actually write:

```
    int *ages = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2, -1}; // Illegal
```

This is because the compiler won't let you assign an implicit array to a pointer. If you REALLY want to, you can write:

```
    int *ages = (int *) (int []) {23, 43, 12, 89, 2, -1}; // Horrible style
```

But don't, because it is extremely unpleasant to read. For the purposes of this exercise, I would probably write:

```
    int ages_array[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2, -1};
    int *ages_pointer = ages_array;
```

Note that the compiler is "decaying" the array name to a pointer to it's first element there - it's as if you had written:

```
    int ages_array[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2, -1};
    int *ages_pointer = &(ages_array[0]);
```

However - you can also dynamically allocate the arrays. For this example code, it will become quite wordy, but we can do it as a learning exercise. Instead of writing:

```
int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
```

We could allocate the memory using malloc:

```
int *ages = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); // create enough space for 5 integers
if (ages == NULL) { 
   /* we're out of memory, print an error and exit */ 
}
ages[0] = 23;
ages[1] = 43;
ages[2] = 12;
ages[3] = 89;
ages[4] = 2;
```

Note that we then need to free `ages` when we're done with the memory:

```
free(ages);
```

Note also that there are a few ways to write the malloc call:

```
 int *ages = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

This is clearer to read for a beginner, but generally considered bad style because there are two places you need to change if you change the type of `ages`. Instead, you can write either of:

```
 int *ages = malloc(sizeof(ages[0]) * 5);
 int *ages = malloc(sizeof(*ages) * 5);
```

These statements are equivalent - which you choose is a matter of personal style. I prefer the first one.

---

One final thing - if we're changing the code over to use arrays, you might look at changing this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

But, you don't need to. The reason why is a little subtle. First, this declaration:

```
char *argv[]
```

says "there is an array of pointers-to-char called argv". However, the compiler treats arrays in function arguments as a pointer to the first element of the array, so if you write:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

The compiler will actually see:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

This is also the reason that you can omit the length of the first dimension of a multidimensional array used as a function argument - the compiler won't see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This cleared up stuff for me quite significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The task of "rewriting the code with pointer usage instead of array usage" is not sufficiently clearly formulated to make sense. In C language 99.9% (just an informal number) of array functionality is based on the implicit array-to-pointer conversion, meaning that virtually every time you use arrays, you use pointers as well. There's no way around it.

In other words, formally there's really no need to rewrite anything.

If you rewrite your code by doing

```
int *ptr = &ages[0];
```

and using `ptr` in place of `ages`, you will simply make explicit something that was already present in your code implicitly. If that's what is really meant by that task, then you can certainly do that. But I don't see much point in such a reduntant excercise.

Comment: This is a long winded "don't bother", not an answer.

Comment: @Jake Sellers: No, this is not a "don't bother". This is a "more info needed" and a "if they didn't provide more info, they don't know themselves what they are asking".

Comment: Comments are for asking for more info, not answers.

Comment: @Jake Sellers: I'm not asking for more info. I'm not the one who's been assigned the problem in question. I'm just telling the OP what in my opinion *his* actions in this situation should be. Moreover, if I were in his place, I would treat this as a *trick question*, to which "it doesn't make sense" is actually the correct and *final* answer. And if I were the one asking this question, this is exactly the answer I would expect to receive from someone who knows what they are talking about.

Comment: The purpose of the question has been identified and was clear to myself immediately, it may be an ambiguous question in the context that it is aimed at people trying to learn, but that doesn't make your non-answer any more an answer, or this argument any less pointless.  The fact is this not an answer to his question.  Of course there is no NEED to re-write anything, that is not the point, and the single line of code you posted is a simple what not to do.

Comment: @Jake Sellers: To learn? You are preaching to the choir. The whole point of my answer is that understanding the implicit meaning of the problem (even if not intended by question's authors) will teach the beginner a lot more than mindless rewriting of the code "with pointers" just for the sake of the sake of rewriting it "with pointers".

Answer (score 0):

It probably means something like what you suggested, yeah.

Keep in mind, though, that `ages` is already an int pointer (`int *`) -- an array, in C, is just a bunch of things all next to each other in memory. A variable that represents that array is just a pointer to the first element in that array, and the `[]` operator is a dereference.

You can think of it like this:

There's a chunk of memory somewhere as your program is running that contains
`|...| 23 | 43 | 12 | 89 | 2 |...|`
Where each box represents enough space to hold one `int`.
The variable `ages` in your program, then, is just a pointer that holds the address of the first element in that chunk.  It "points to" the `23`, and has type `int*`. If you dereference that, you'll find that `*ages` evaluates to 23.  Similarly, if you take that address and "skip" one `int`-size forward, you'll get `43`.  In code, this would look like
`*(ages + 1 * sizeof(int))`
where you can replace the `1` with however many elements you want to skip.  Because this is really ugly and confusing, C provides you a nice way of doing exactly the same thing: the `[]` operator. In general,

`some_array[n] == *(some_array + n * sizeof(array_element_type))`

Hope that helps, and good luck learning C!  Make sure you take the time to really understand the equality of arrays and pointers; it will make a lot of stuff a lot harder later on if you don't.

Comment: No, it wants him to learn about similarities and differences between pointers and arrays, if it wanted to teach him about de-referencing pointers it would teach him about de-referencing pointers.  You can read how they are often interchangeable but different [here](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr) question 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it means

1. Allocate memory for each array using `malloc()` and release the memory using `free()`.
2. Use pointer arithmetic in all for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to change `ages` and `names` to be pointers without using dynamic allocation.

```
  // create two arrays we care about
  const char *ages = "\x17\x2b\x0c\x59\x02";
  const char (*names)[6] = (void *)
      "Alan\0\0" "Frank\0" "Mary\0\0" "John\0\0" "Lisa\0\0";

  // safely get the size of ages
  int count = strlen(ages);

  //...

  // setup the pointers to the start of the arrays
  const char *cur_age = ages;
  const char (*cur_name)[6] = names;
```

`names` and `cur_name` are both pointer types, although they do point to arrays.

Comment: Fortunately, people don't live for multiple centuries (anymore? yet?). So, people's ages fit in a byte. [Proof that it works.](http://ideone.com/H1jfCl)