# How to split char* into 3 char* at delimiter?

Tags: c, string, char

I want to split a `char* time = "15:18:13";` into `char* hour;`, `char* minute;` and `char* seconds;`.

The problem is that I don't know how. I am like to try a Pebble Watchface. I already used `char* hour = strok(time, ":");` but the first parameter needs to be a `char[]` but time is a `char*`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `strtok_s` does what you want, iff the input may be modified. String literals are constants, even though they have type `char[]` for historic reasons. You might need a `strdup` first (`strlen`+`malloc`+`memcpy`). Anyway, in your case a simple scan to numbers using `sscanf(s, "%d:%d:%d",...)` might be best.

Comment: Use Data Object don't split it !!!

Comment: If you use `strdup`, I suggest you implement your own, since it is not standard! ;)

Comment: Did you read the man page, especially the BUGS section?

Comment: If it's about scanning/parsing time/date strings you might like to use the `strptime()` function.

Comment: strftime is the best way

Answer (score 2):

Based on alk's comment, the approach one can use is `sscanf`, like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char* str = "15:18:13";
  int a, b, c;
  sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &a, &b, &c);
  printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
  return 0;
}
```

However, the following is a more general solution.

Use `strtok`.
You can store them in an array, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="15:18:13";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,":");
  char* a[3];
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    a[i] = malloc( (strlen(pch)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a[i++], pch);
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ":");
  }

  for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    printf ("%s\n",a[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

`strdup`, as suggested by Deduplicator, can also help, but it is not standard, thus I suggest to avoid (or implement your own, not that hard). :)

Moreover, `strtok_s` that Deduplicator mentions is not provided in C.

Reply to OP's comment below:

Question: str is char str[] but time is a char*. Can I convert this?

You can assign it to an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char* from = "15:18:13";
  char to[strlen(from) + 1]; // do not forget +1 for the null character!
  strcpy(to, from);
  printf("%s\n", to);
  return 0;
}
```

GIFT: I suggest you read the first answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627962/is-it-possible-to-convert-char-to-char-in-c).

It provides a smooth explanation to `char*` and `char[]`.

Comment: The OP's use-case is to parse a constant.

Comment: This only works if the time, so str is char str[] but time is a char*. Can I convert this?

Comment: @DavidG., if my answer is what you are looking for, accept it or notify me, so that I don't worry no more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need those api. Pebble has own api for time out: **strftime**

```
tm *tmNext = localtime(&timeRequestTmp);
static char strformatForTimeNext[10];
strftime(strformatForTimeNext,10,"%H:%M",tmNext);
text_layer_set_text(layer_nextTime, strformatForTimeNext);
```