# Pass struct from C to Java JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I have a struct and I would like to pass its fields from C to Java with JNI.

The struct:

```
typedef struct {
  short headerCount;
  short lineCount;
  screenLine *headers;
  screenLine *lines;
}ScrollList;
```

and `screenLine` is:

```
typedef char screenLine[ 26 ];
```

My method in C:

```
short SrvSelect_GetScrollListSelection( ScrollList *list)
{
...
}
```

I succeed to pass both shorts to Java, but I struggle to pass the last two fields:

```
    jshort headerCount = list->headerCount;
    jshort lineCount = list->lineCount;
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/43986751/17635987 ?

Comment: This is not possible to answer without knowing how the Java side will use those variables/members. Do you expect modifications on the Java side to show up on the native side as well? If not this is a trivial combination of `NewByteArray` and `SetByteArrayRegion`.

Comment: @Botje no changes whatsoever on Java side, just for displaying stuff on the UI level.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `headerCount` and `lineCount` are the corresponding number of items in `headers` and `lines`:

```
jobjectarray jHeaders = env->NewObjectArray(list->headerCount, "[B", NULL);
for (int h = 0; h < list->headerCount; h++) {
  jbyteArray jHeader = env->NewByteArray(26);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(jHeader, 0, 26, list->headers[h]);
  env->SetObjectArrayElement(jHeaders, h, jHeader);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(jHeader);
}
```

Alternatively, if each screenLine fits in Java's "modified UTF-8" (or is just ASCII):

```
jobjectarray jHeaders = env->NewObjectArray(list->headerCount, "Ljava/lang/String;", NULL);
for (int h = 0; h < list->headerCount; h++) {
  jbyteArray jHeader = env->NewStringUTF(list->headers[h]);
  env->SetObjectArrayElement(jHeaders, h, jHeader);
  env->DeleteLocalRef(jHeader);
}
```